# Strong Entity Refer to Its Weak Entity

Tags: database, database-design

I have 2 tables called Group and Person, the Group is the strong entity and the Person is the weak one.

Group (PK_Group, Name, ...)

Person (PK_Group, PK_Person, Name, ...)

The problem is, how to add group leader to the tables. Is adding Flag_Leader to Person table is a good design? Any recommendation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a foreign key `leader_id` to the group that references the person leading this group. The leader flag you consider makes constraints to make sure that each group has exactly one leader more complicated.

Before deciding on that, I would reconsider your primary key strategy. Did I get it right that your idea is to include the PK_Group in the primary key of the Person? This makes the group membership an identifying property of the person. If, one day, a person may be a member of more than one group, or a person may move from one group to another, you'll be in trouble. So if you design this database from scratch and are not bound by any previous legacy data structures, you should define a key for each table that has just the purpose to identify, not to describe the data object.

So my suggestion is:

```
group(pk_id, name, fk_leader_id, ...)
person(pk_id, name, fk_group_id, ...)
```

where `fk` means foreign key.

Comment: my table design is only simple explanation of my real trouble. To clear up, there is constraint that person cannot join multiple group.